# UnityContainer configured in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have the following code

```
var container = new UnityContainer();                       //LINE 1
container.RegisterType<ILogUtility,LogUtil>();              //LINE 2
var logger = container.Resolve<Logger>();                   //LINE 3
logger.Log(LogType.Warn, "logging from container");         //LINE 4
```

How do I implement line 2 in web.config such that I will only have to code line 1, 3, and 4 in my code behind? I have searched every where for code example but they are not clear.

Thanks

Comment: See how it's done in [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/03/27/ioc-and-unity-configuration-changes-for-the-better.aspx)

Comment: oleksii, thanks for the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at my tutorial

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/11/unity-application-block-is-lightweight.html

There's an example XML configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">       
<container>        
<register type="ConsoleApplication30.Logic.ICustomService, ConsoleApplication30"                  
          mapTo="ConsoleApplication30.Logic.CustomServiceImpl, ConsoleApplication30" />    
</container></unity>
```

and you load it with

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();                
container.LoadConfiguration();
```